# Subgroups of prime order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We know that if $G$ is a group and $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$, each of order $p$, where $p$ is a prime number, then $H\cap K=\{e\}$ or $H=K$. Now show that this does not hold when $p$ is not prime.

Comment: additional tags needed

Comment: I think you mean $H\cap K=\{e\}$.

Comment: What is the reason behind the down vote I received for the question ? Is there any typing error or the material is unclear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_4$ be a symmetric group with $4$ letters and $H=\langle (1,2,3),(1,2)\rangle$ and $K=\langle (1,2,4),(1,2)\rangle$. It is not hard to see that $H$ and $K$ are proper subgroups and they are both of order $6$.

Note that $(1,2)\in H\cap K$.

Comment: Theoretically solved so it needs UV +1

Answer (score 2):

Another attempt may arise by using not updated version of [GAP](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/) as follows:

```
gap> LoadPackage("sonata");;
     z:=DihedralGroup(IsPermGroup,8);
     e:=Subgroups(z);

   Group(()), Group([ (1,3)(2,4) ]), Group([ (2,4) ]), Group([ (1,3) ]), 
   Group([ (1,2)(3,4) ]), Group([ (1,4)(2,3) ]), Group([ (1,3)(2,4), (2,4) ]), 
   Group([ (1,3)(2,4), (1,2,3,4) ]), Group([ (1,3)(2,4), (1,2)(3,4) ]), 
   Group([ (1,3)(2,4), (2,4), (1,2,3,4) ])
```

Now the following subgroups `e[8]` and `e[7]` satisfy our aim:

```
gap> Elements(e[8]);
   [ (), (1,2,3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4,3,2) ]

gap> Elements(e[7]);
   [ (), (2,4), (1,3), (1,3)(2,4) ]
```

Comment: I don't think that your GAP is old. Since you load "Sonata"

Comment: @Babgen: Yes! :D I mean it is not updated as we have access to new version. Thanks.

Comment: @Babgen: I guess B.S. has in mind that since in GAP 4.5 one could do the same using `AllSubgroups` without loading the Sonata package. Anyhow, both `AllSubgroups` and `Subgroups` are suitable only for small examples like the one above, while for larger one should follow http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.7

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Thanks. Yes. I mean that. Honestly, I was working with this older one and so I did this basic program by its platform. Unless, the latest version is suggested instead.  :-)

Comment: @B.S.: yes, unfortunately, GGAP interface (which may be the feature you find particularly attractive in your GAP 4.4.12 installation) has not been updated to work with GAP 4.5 and further releases. See http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/changes/chap2.html to see which new features and bugfixes were introduced in post-GAP 4.4 releases to decide whether it's fine to continue with GAP 4.4.12 for your purposes or not.

Comment: @B.S. yes, go ahead please.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Don't the Masters, who supports GAP to be a potent powerful software in, think about making practical this tool for the genius phones like Iphone whose Operating Systems are IOS or Android? Sorry if my question is ridiculous, it is just an idea. Thanks. :-)